# Unable to bind to "list" attribute of input element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am unable to bind to the [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdeflist) attribute of an input element using `[list]="..."` syntax. I get the error

> Can't bind to 'list' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Obviously, if I just use `list="..."` in the template it works. But I need to be able to bind to a component variable.

UPDATE: I'll try to make it clearer why I need to bind like this: `[list]`.

My code looks like this:

**component.ts**

```js
public arr = [
  {
    name: 'Input1',
    autocomp: [1, 5, 10, 22],
  },
  {
    name: 'Input2',
    autocomp: [0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
  },
  {
    name: 'Input3',
    autocomp: [4, 5, 6],
  },
];
```

**component.html**

```html
<input *ngFor="let item of arr" [id]="item.name" />
<datalist *ngFor="let item of arr" [id]="item.name + '-datalist'">
  <option *ngFor="let num of item.autocomp" [value]="num">{{ num }}</option>
</datalist>
```

Each `input` needs to reference the corresponding datalist. Ideally, I would just do:

```html
<input *ngFor="let item of arr" [id]="item.name" [list]="item.name + '-datalist'" />
```

But this gives me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to bind an attribute on a native element, you should do it like that :

```
<input [attr.list]="myDynamicId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1diur) You can try `list="dataListId"` rather than `[list]="param"`

`[list]` is binding method. But for autocomplete options. You need to give dataset id to input so you don't need to bind anything just give id of datalist

for html

```
<input list="browsers">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option *ngFor="let data of datas" value="{{data}}">
</datalist>
```

for component.ts

```
datas=[ "test1","test2","abc","xyz"]
```

Comment: Are u using for datalist ?